# Putting image in Nav Bar

Tags: css, materialize

I want to add `image/logo inside Nav Bar`.
How to make sure that the nav bar height always fit the image and the other elements stay in center.

I am currently using nav bar with `Nav-wrapper` class from `materialize` framework.

I have tried to add min-height to `nav-wrapper` but that make the other elements slide off from the center.

[Code pen link](https://codepen.io/Velocodes/pen/VMdmWV)

Comment: please put your code

Comment: The code is in that codepen link. https://codepen.io/Velocodes/pen/VMdmWV

Answer (score 1):

Try like this its working for me

**step-01**  Im added this class  `navbar-brand`

**step-02**  Im added this CSS

```
.navbar-brand {

  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto; 
}



.black {
    background-color: #111 !important;
}
```

**nav**

```
<nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper black">
         <div class="container">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="http://www.becomeanengagedemployee.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/flow-200x75.jpg"></a>
          <ul id="Nav2" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons right">refresh</i>Link with Left Icon</a></li>
            <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Button</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzEXEx)

Comment: Thx for the reply Core, I notice it adjust the picture to be smaller. Is there a way to have same size image and enlarge the bar area instead?